# how to match a string which is not (double underscored and double dashed and spaces)

Tags: python, regex, search

I would like to match any strings which does not contain -- and __ and spaces.

**Strings that should match**

```
asd_asd-qwem
asd_-asd-_qwem
asdasdqwem
```

**Strings that should NOT match**

```
asd_asd--qwem
asd__asd-qwem
asd__asd--qwem
```

Comment: What about the rest of the string?  Is it just letters, letters and digits, or what?  Can the string begin or end with `-` or `_`?  Are you matching against standalone strings, or searching for matches within a larger string?

Comment: By saying spaces, do you mean that you can accept one space? If not, `any space` would be more accurate than `spaces`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you added `regex` tag here is my solution for the same.

**Regex:** `^(?!.*(--|__| +)).+$`

**Explanation:**

- `(?!.*(--|__| +))` will look for **absence** of `__`, `--` or `spaces`. If none of them is present then whole string will be a match.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yR6rB9/1)**

Comment: is there a way to group the matched pattern in a named group? Just like how (?p<name>) work?

Comment: @noob: Just a step reduction (-40) with a lazy quantifier and a positive lookahead in the negative one: [`^(?!.*?(?=--|__| +)).+$`](https://regex101.com/r/yR6rB9/2)

Comment: @Jan: Thanx for that. However I will keep previous one as answer because then I will have to explain that nested `lookaround` to OP, which will be a little complicated. I encourage you to add this as your answer explaining that one.

Comment: @lionel319: Yes you can use that. More about [named groups](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you could just do:

```
if not ('--' in s or '__' in s):
    ...
```

Or, equivalently:

```
if '--' not in s and '__' not in s:
    ...
```

Comment: ah i'm stupid. I do not need re.search() for that to happen. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

A non-regex alternative approach may involve checking substrings in a string:

```
>>> l = ["asd_asd-qwem", "asd_-asd-_qwem", "asdasdqwem", "asd_asd--qwem", "asd__asd-qwem", "asd__asd--qwem"]
>>> c = ["--", "__", " "]
>>> [s for s in l if not any(item in s for item in c)]
['asd_asd-qwem', 'asd_-asd-_qwem', 'asdasdqwem']
```

where `c` defines a list of substrings we don't want to see in our string.

Comment: ah i'm stupid. I do not need re.search() for that to happen. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you really need a regular expression, you could come up with sth. like:

```
^(?!.*?(?=--|__| +)).+$
```

This breaks down to the following:

- `^` makes sure to anchor the string to the beginning
- `(?!` is a *negative* lookahead
- `.*?` matches any character except a newline lazily
- `(?=` is a *positive* lookahead with one of `--` or `__` or spaces
- `.+` match at least *one* character
- `$` make sure the string ends here

The nested lookaheads are there to allow a reduction in steps for the regex engine (thus making the engine come to an end faster), see<kbd>[a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yR6rB9/2)</kbd> (hijacked from @noob, sorry :).
In `Python` this would be:

```
import re
rx = r'^(?!.*?(?=--|__| +)).+$'
string = """
asd_asd-qwem
asd_-asd-_qwem
asdasdqwem

asd_asd--qwem
asd__asd-qwem
asd__asd--qwem
"""

for match in re.finditer(rx, string, re.MULTILINE):
    print match.group(0)
# asd_asd-qwem, asd_-asd-_qwem, asdasdqwem
```

See <kbd>[a demo on ideone.com.](http://ideone.com/kwkFMA)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern should be easy to understand:

```
^(?:[^_\s-]|_(?!_)|-(?!-))+$
```

**REGEX EXPLANATION:**

```
^               # Assert start of line  
 (?:            # Non-capturing group starts
    [^_\s-]|    # match a character except underscore, space, dash; OR
    _(?!_)|     # match underscore, but not followed by another underscore; OR
    -(?!-)      # match dash, but not followed by another dash
 )              # Non-capturing group ends
  +             # Repeat above pattern 1 or more times
$               # Assert end of line
```

[**REGEX DEMO.**](https://regex101.com/r/pB1iW1/2)